# How to reset PowerMockito.whenNew() behavior?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

This is what I'm doing:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(null);
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
assert foo1 == null; // works fine
//...
// now I want PowerMockito to stop mocking the call
Foo foo2 = new Foo(); 
assert foo2 != null;
```

I can't find `PowerMockito.reset()` method.. What is a workaround?

Comment: It's not possible at the moment: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=281

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MockRepository.remove(Foo.class);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you *think* that this works or you *know for a fact* that this works? Your answer makes this kind of unclear.

Comment: @Thunderforge It worked for me.. It doesn't exactly say that that is what it is supposed to be used for in the javadoc though.

Also this doesn't seem to reset a mock. Instead it seems to set it up like it was never mocked in the first place.